# Wants next Stack<T> from the list of Actions

Tags: c#, wpf, stack, undo-redo

I am making a **UndoRedo Functionlity** for my application. Now on function **`DoAction`** I have the list of Action taken in **`Stack<UndoRedoAction>`** Now I want to get the Last Action Taken Which automatically will be First in the List To take out the First in the List I have used **`actionList.Peek();`** Now the Situation arise is that the next time I wanted to take the second one from the list. I am not sure how to do that

```
private void DoAction(Stack<UndoRedoAction> actionList, Stack<UndoRedoAction> storeList, Action<UndoRedoAction> action)
{
    if (actionList.Count > 0)
    {
        UndoRedoAction urAction = actionList.Peek();
        action(urAction);
        storeList.Push(urAction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Stack<T>.Pop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9say334k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Peek`. `Pop` removes the last added item in the stack and returns it while `Peek` returns the last added item without removing it from the stack.

Comment: I never thought of this. Lemme try :)

Comment: Silly me. While creating the flow I was aware that I want to remove the first one and That is the reason I was adding the Current Action in `storeList` and again for the reason of Redo. But I forgot. Thanks Your **`Pop`** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pop for sure (as @Matias) said.

Also check out the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) as it is perfect for getting abstraction between the code that actually does the work and provides a great basis for undo.